# Import data from one MS Access database into another MS Access database

Tags: c#, ms-access

I am trying to import data from one MS Access database into another MS Access database and have found the following works fine, problem I have got is does anybody know what I should be using if the from database is locked with a SYSTEM.MDW

```
string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\Data\Database1.mdb;User Id=admin;Password=;";
string commandText = "INSERT INTO [TableName] SELECT * FROM [MS Access;DATABASE=C:\\Data\Database2.mdb].[TableName]";

try
{
    using (OleDbConnection oleConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (OleDbCommand oleCommand = new OleDbCommand(commandText, oleConnection))
        {
            oleCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            oleCommand.Connection.Open();
            oleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();      
        }
    }

}
catch (Exception)
{
    throw;
}
```

I can open the From database using `Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Data\Database2.MDB;System Database=C:\Data\SYSTEM.MDW;User ID=Developer;Password=Password`

Comment: Can this action be done when From DB is not protected in a SYSTEM.MDW? I would guess you need the Access environment to be **opened**, and run the INSERT statement. I may be wrong, of course...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can open the *From* database, open it and do the action from it:

```
string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Data\Database2.MDB;System Database=C:\Data\SYSTEM.MDW;User ID=Developer;Password=Password";
string commandText = "INSERT INTO [TableName] In 'C:\\Data\Database1.mdb' SELECT * FROM [TableName]";
try
{
    using (OleDbConnection oleConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (OleDbCommand oleCommand = new OleDbCommand(commandText, oleConnection))
        {
            oleCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            oleCommand.Connection.Open();
            oleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();      
        }
    }

}
catch (Exception)
{
    throw;
}
```